# Detecting eloquent firstOrNew

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```
$listing = Listing::firstOrNew(['internal_id' => $internalId]);
```

Is there a way to detect whether $listing is first or new?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.  Eloquent as an `exists` property.

```
if ($listing->exists) {

    // it's an existing row

}
```